# Where are all the places Sql Reporting Server Logs Errors?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

It seems like Sql Reporting Services Server logs information in several places including web server logs and logging tables in the database. Where are all the locations SSRS logs to, and what type of errors are logged in each place?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I know SSRS logs to the Event Log, the filesystem and its own database.

The database is typically the most easily available one. You just login to the ReportServer database and execute

```
select * from executionlog
```

This only logs the executions though. If you want more information you can go to the Trace Log files, which are usually available at (location may of course vary):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

These are quite verbose and not really fun to look through. But they do log a lot of stuff.

If you're searching for an error you can go to the Windows Application Log (Under Administrative Tools in your control panel)

**Edit** Found a nice link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources

Answer (score 5):

For SSRS 2008 R2:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles